# Improve time complexity of this code

Tags: java, time-complexity, fibonacci

Can anyone here please help me to reduce the time complexity of this code:

```
public static int a(int number) {
      if ((number == 0) || (number == 1))
         return number;
      else
         return a(number - 1) + a(number - 2);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       System.out.print("Enter the count of Fibonacci series: ");
        int cap = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();

        System.out.println("Output: ");
      for (int i = 1; i <= cap; i++){
         System.out.printf("%d\n", a(i));
      }
   }
```

Comment: Hint: if I asked you the value of fib(10) and you didn't have a compute - just pencil and paper - what would you do?

Answer (score 0):

You can store previously calculated values, so if you try calculate fibonnaci(100) you don't calculate fibonacci(50) about 100 times.

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo code:

```
 dictA = {}

 a(n):

    if n in dictA: 
        return dictA[n]
    else if n <= 1: 
        return n
    else: 
        val = a(n-1) + a(n-2)
        dictA[n] = val
        return val
```

Answer (score 0):

It is quite simple to add some cache, where you will store already calculated values. If you want exactly the recursive algorithm the idea will be the same - just check in the beginning of routine if the value already calculated. If yes - return it from cache, else - start calculate (do not forget to save it after calculation ended).

```
public class Fibbonaci {

    public static long calc(int n) {

        List<Integer> cache = new ArrayList<>();
        cache.add(1);
        cache.add(2);

        for (int i = 2; i < n; i++) {
            cache.add(cache.get(i - 1) + cache.get(i - 2));
        }

        return cache.get(n - 1);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        IntStream.range(1, 10)
            .forEach(n -> System.out.println("Fibb " + n + " = " + calc(n)));
    }

}
```